# using prefix binding along with Key-chord binding

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

I am using my capslock key as a prefix key and have already set "capslock-v" to 'helm-show-kill-ring. This however does not work with copying outside code into emacs so now I want a set up as such:

capslock-v (wait 1 sec) 'helm-show-kill-ring

and

capslock-vv 'yank

Is it possible to do this? Here is the relevant portion of my .emacs

```
(setq w32-enable-caps-lock nil)

(progn
  ;; define a prefix keymap
  (define-prefix-command 'my-modes-key-map)

  (define-key my-modes-key-map (kbd "v") 'helm-show-kill-ring)  
  (key-chord-define my-modes-key-map (kbd "vv") 'yank) 

  )

(global-set-key (kbd "<capslock>") my-modes-key-map)
```